# Override model field with a getter in Django/Python 2.7?

Tags: django-models, python-2.7

Given a Django model such as:

```
class Grouping(models.Model):
    title           = models.CharField(max_length=1024,null=True,blank=True)
    slug            = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True,editable=False)
```

How can I add a getter functionality to a field like `slug`?  Here I'd like to modify the slug prior to return, without having to modify every place that slug is used.

I am aware of https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/3148

Comment: hmm the bug report is updated with another third party solution only 3 month ago